# Get Textbox value with TextMode="Password" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a Asp.net TextBox with TextMode="Password": 
`<asp:TextBox ID="txtAuthPwd" runat="server" TextMode="Password"/>`

I need to get the value of this TextBox from the javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function someFunc() {
        var pwd = document.getElementById("<%=txtAuthPwd.ClientID%>").value;
    }
</script>
```

But the value is always empty. Please help...

Comment: are you sure about txtAuthPwd.ClientID ??
check the source code of the html

Comment: Yup, @salahy is right- your code should work. Are you sure someFunc() is getting called? Any javascript errors?

Answer (score 2):

Please check my code as below and it's working.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPwd" TextMode="Password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" Text="Click" runat="server" OnClientClick="return test();" />


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function test() {
        var pwd = (document.getElementById("<%= txtPwd.ClientID %>").value);
        alert(pwd);
        return false;
    }
</script>
```